# Given only this graph of a certain cosine function, how can I determine what it's "c" is? (click to see graph)

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Although my answer key says $c$ is supposedly $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, I actually get $c = \frac{4\pi}{3}$

Thus, $y$ should equal $\frac{5}{2}cos(\frac{\pi(x)}{2}-\frac{4\pi}{3})-0.5$ , right?

Comment: It _does_ look like the answer key is wrong: your result gets the axis intercepts correct and theirs doesn't.  I suspect the solver got the sign of the phase shift confused: their value for $ \ c \ $ would be right if the expression were $ \ \cos \ (\frac{\pi}{2}x \ + \ c \ ) \ $ .  Your answer would give $ \ \frac{5}{2} \cos(\frac{\pi}{2} [x - \frac{8}{3}]) \ $ , which puts the maximum of the curve in the right place.

Comment: Reckless, thank you for assuring me that I haven't gone completely insane yet. If I had hair, I'm sure I would have pulled it all out  by now.

Comment: If your instructor or someone else doesn't believe you, tell them to graph the offered answer, and then yours.  I think they lost track of the direction of the phase shift...